# Wrong tuple size for returned value. Expected 23, got 13 in SNOWFLAKE Python UDTF function?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have registered a Python udtf. This udtf performs data processing using the `pandas` library - groupby and pivot operations for feature engineering process. At the end it returns 23 columns.

When I call this udtf using the select statement and partition over by () command, it gives me the following error:

```
Wrong tuple size for returned value. Expected 23, got 13 in function.
```

However, I have implemented the same processing using classes and functions in Sagemaker, it return a dataframe with 23 columns. This means that everything is working fine with correct structure is defining and sharing variables across the different functions.

But unfortunately, this doesn't seem working in Snowflake udtf. Also, another interesting thing is that the udtf return different results when calling the same registered function. For example,

at time t: `Wrong tuple size for returned value. Expected 23, got 13 in function.`

at t+1, `Wrong tuple size for returned value. Expected 23, got 21 in function.`, then `Wrong tuple size for returned value. Expected 23, got 3 in function.` and so on.

I am new to udtf and looking for some suggestions to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the UDTF so we can understand why this is happening?

Comment: Hey @Sergiu, it's a huge one. Could you refer to the following link where I have shared the code in the text file: 
    https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000V64MJKAZ/wrong-tuple- size-for-returned-value-expected-23-got-13-in-function

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snwoflake UDTF accepts multiple rows of data as an input, process them together in batches known as partitions and returns a table of values as an output. While performing the groupby operation on certain categories, the udtf returned null rows for missing categories in the input data. And, hence I got the error of wrong tuple size. While using Sagemaker, the pandas library process the complete dataframe at once. However, udtf processes them in partitions.

I was able to solve this issue by adding these lines of code:

```
df_subset['CATEGORY'] = df_subset['THIRD_PARTY'].astype('category')
df_subset['CATEGORY']=df_subset['THIRD_PARTY'].cat.set_categories(list_of_categories)
```

With this, the missing categories for various partitions were filled as nan values. Pivot worked fine using the following code:

```
unique_pivot = ((groupdf.pivot(index="CLIENT_ID", columns="CATEGORY", values= [f"{category_name}_MEAN", f"{category_name}_STD"])).reset_index()
```